# How to access variable or argument of function outside the function in R?

Tags: r, user-defined-functions

I am creating a plot and for its data preparation I have created a function that needs year start and end values as arguments of the function:

```
fn_gapminder_benchmark_diff  <- function(year_start = 1952, year_end = 2007){
  
                              year_start = year_start
                              year_end = year_end
                              
                              gapminder_joined %>% 
                              filter(year %in% c(year_start,year_end)) %>% 
                              arrange(country, year) %>%                               
                              group_by(country) %>%                               
                              mutate(benchmark_diff = benchmarked_india[2] - benchmarked_india[1],
                                     max_pop = max(pop)) %>% 
                              
                              ungroup() %>%                               
                              arrange(benchmark_diff) %>%                               
                              filter(max_pop > 30000000) %>%                               
                              mutate(country = droplevels(country)) %>% 
                              select(country, year, continent, benchmarked_india, benchmark_diff)
}

fn_gapminder_benchmark_diff(1987, 2007)
```

Above function is called in below code

**Issue** is I am unable to use above function `arguments or variable values` in the `title` of the chart to keep `years` dynamic in the chart title

```
# data function
  fn_gapminder_benchmark_diff(1987, 2007) %>% 

# data prep  
    mutate(country = fct_inorder(country)) %>% 
    
    group_by(country) %>% 
      
    mutate(benchmarked_end = benchmarked_india[2],
           benchmarked_start = benchmarked_india[1]  ) %>% 
    
    ungroup() %>% 
  
# plotting
    ggplot() +
      
    geom_vline(xintercept = 0, col = "blue", alpha = 0.5) +
    geom_label( label="India - As Benchamrking line", x=0, y="United States",
      label.padding = unit(0.55, "lines"), # Rectangle size around label
      label.size = 0.35, color = "black") +
    
    geom_segment(aes(x = benchmarked_start, xend = benchmarked_end,
                     y = country, yend = country,
                     col = continent), alpha = 0.5, size = 7) +
    
    geom_point(aes(x = benchmarked_india, y = country, col = continent), size = 9, alpha = .6) +
    
    scale_color_brewer(palette = "Pastel2") +
    
    labs(title = sprintf("GdpPerCapita Differenece with India (Starting point at %i and Ending at %i)",year_start, year_end),
         subtitle = "Benchmarked India in blue line \nFor Countries with pop > 30000000 \n(Chart created by ViSa)",
         col = "Continent", x = "GdpPerCap Difference at 1952 & 2007") +
    
# background & theme settings
    theme_classic() +
    
    theme(legend.position = "top", 
          axis.line = element_blank(),
          axis.ticks = element_blank(),
          axis.text = element_blank()
          )
```

Below is the image of static chart that I have build and trying to make its title dynamic

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is unfortunately not reproducible. Maybe next time use the [reprex](https://github.com/tidyverse/reprex) package to get answers better tailored to your needs.

Making an example with the `iris` data, I have a quick fix for you that follows the same logic but is, in my opinion, rather dirty:

```r
library(tidyverse)

data_prep <- function(data, species, min_sepal_w) {
  
  species <<- species         # use superassignment operator to assign to global environment
  min_sepal_w <<- min_sepal_w
  
  data %>% 
    filter(species == species,
           Sepal.Width >= min_sepal_w)
}

iris %>% 
  data_prep(species = "setosa", min_sepal_w = 3.0) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(title = sprintf("Scatterplot of species %s with minimum sepal with of %i)", species, min_sepal_w))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-09-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

A much cleaner solution would be to store the information in the data:

```r
data_prep <- function(data, species, min_sepal_w) {
  
  species <<- species
  min_sepal_w <<- min_sepal_w
  
  data %>% 
    filter(species == species,
           Sepal.Width >= min_sepal_w) %>% 
    mutate(species = species,
           min_sepal_w = min_sepal_w)
}
```

Otherwise the code above can stay the same.

Comment: yes, its a much cleaner way to do it and thanks for helping me out on this and letting me know about reprex package. Will surely use reprex in future !!